# How to express "They only think about themselves"

Tags: grammar, words, idioms

I am trying to come up with this sentence, but I feel like some parts of it are too literal and idiomatic, and some words I used here are new to me, so maybe I made some poor decisions when picking them. Could you help me with that?

**"Sometimes I feel like most people only think about themselves. If they need your help, they'll contact you. If they don't need it (if you're not useful to them) they won't contact you at all, like they don't care(it's not their business)"**

> 時々、ほとんどの人は自分についてだけを考える感じがある。手伝ってほしかったら、連絡する。君は有用じゃなかったら、全然連絡しなくて、関係ない感じがある

I feel like "think about themselves" is idiomatic and i'm not so sure about the usage of "useful" here.

Comment: 君は有用じゃなかったら…関係ない感じがある means "you look indifferent to those who are not useful" and never "if you".

Comment: @user4092 I meant to use tara form to express "if"/"when" hmmm why didn't I get that result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about...

Sometimes I feel like most people only think about themselves.
たいていの人は自分のことしか考えてない（んじゃないか）って思うときがある。

If they need your help, they'll contact you.
困ったときだけ連絡してきて、

If they don't need it (if you're not useful to them) they won't contact you at all, like they don't care(it's not their business)
用がないときは、「知ったこっちゃない」って感じで、ぜんぜん連絡してこない。

Comment: あっ、助かったね、教えてくれてありがとうございます！！！

Comment: I have one question, If I was going to use んじゃないか it would be 考えてないんじゃないかって思うときがある or 考えてるんじゃないかって思うときがある？

Comment: @Felipe 「しか～ない」means "only", so 自分のこと**しか**考えて**ない** means "they *only* think about themselves". んじゃないか adds a nuance of "I wonder..." or "I suspect...", as in 自分のことしか考えてない+ **んじゃないか** "*I suspect* that they might be only thinking about themselves". (自分のことしか考えてるんじゃないか is ungrammatical.)

Comment: ohh yeah, that one じゃないか which adds the rethorical feel to it, thanks a lot, it's clear now!

Answer (score 1):

It might be an idiom:我田引水(gaden - inn - sui) literal translation: drawing water for one's own field.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know this at all!